# extjs filter grid data in column header textfield

Tags: extjs, panel, extjs4.2

I am trying to understand how the grid header filter works in the column header textfield.

replicated kitchen sink example, can't see the textfield inside the column header.

http://jsfiddle.net/srikanthradix/ghzD9/2/

I defined the company column which I would like to filter

```
{
                text: 'Company (Filter)',
                sortable: false,
                dataIndex: 'company',
                width: 120,
                locked: true,
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield'
                },
                items: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    flex : 1,
                    margin: 2,
                    enableKeyEvents: true,
                    listeners: {
                        keyup: function() {
                            var store = this.up('tablepanel').store;
                            store.clearFilter();
                            if (this.value) {
                                store.filter({
                                    property     : 'company',
                                    value         : this.value,
                                    anyMatch      : true,
                                    caseSensitive : false
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        buffer: 500
                    }
                }
            }
```

and also added the basic setup like setpath, requires, and features

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.2.0-gpl/examples/ux/');

Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.util.*',
    'Ext.state.*',
    'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature'
]);
```

inside the grid

```
 features: [{
            ftype: 'filters'
        }],
```

Could you suggest if I am missing anything else?

Comment: actually, this is working when I run locally not on jsfiddle.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't you like better this plugin: [Grid MultiSearch Plugin](http://extjs.eu/software/ext-grid-multisearch-plugin/)? It is very easy to use, no extra coding of listeners is required.